# How do I get access to FastMM4's RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, fastmm

I'm using Delphi's fastMM memory manager and I fail when I try to use the full debug mode.

I get the following errors when compiling:

```
FastMM\FastMM4.pas(6872) Error: Undeclared identifier: 'RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak'
FastMM\FastMM4.pas(6948) Error: Undeclared identifier: 'UnregisterExpectedMemoryLeak'
FastMM\FastMM4.pas(9269)
import_test.dpr(24) Fatal: Could not compile used unit 'FastMM\FastMM4.pas'
```

The .inc file tells to load the full debug dll. I've already copied the FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll file everywhere. It looks like I should have included something in my project.

I'm probably missing something really obvious.

The Delphi version is 7.

Comment: Even if the DLL was missing (could not be found) this would not cause a compiler error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turn on the `EnableMemoryLeakReporting` directive in the include file `FastMM4Options.inc` by changing it from:

```
{.$define EnableMemoryLeakReporting}
```

to:

```
{$define EnableMemoryLeakReporting}
```

Also read the comments in that file and understand the various options, turn them on/off as needed.

Comment: -1 You should better **not** touch the `FastMM4Options.inc` file (which is global to all applications), but set the `EnableMemoryLeakReporting` compiler conditional at the Project options level.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez If you think you have a better answer go ahead and post it. Your -1 means "This answer is not useful" which of course is an opinion you're entitled to, but I disagree. I think my answer is a valid and good one.

Comment: BTW, the weird thing is the necessity to have EnableMemoryLeakingReporting turned on when you are using FullDebugMode. I was just trying to debug an access violation, memory leaks are another kind of problem.