# FastMM/DXE2 only reporting when using debugger?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastmm

I am trying to use FastMM version 4.99 (according to the comment at the top of `FastMM4.pas`). I have [followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955169/how-do-i-get-access-to-fastmm4s-registerexpectedmemoryleak) [the](http://wiert.me/2009/07/29/delphi-fastmm-using-fastmm4-for-debugging-your-memory-allocations-part-1-introduction/) [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271850/how-to-track-down-tricky-memory-leak-with-fastmm) to use full debug mode with stack tracing, and am finding leaks when I run my .exe under the IDE debugger. *e.g.*

[image: FastMM Leak Report Dialog]

But when I try running the executable from a command prompt, or by double-clicking in Windows Explorer, I get no leaks reported. The UnicodeString leaks might be bogus, but I know for sure that the TIniFile leaks are real. How can I make FastMM report/log leaks when not using the debugger?

UPDATE: This project also uses madExcept 3.0n: the .dpr file does have FastMM4 as the first item in its uses clause. Is anything else needed to make these two coexist?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't properly configured `FastMM4Options.inc`. From the file distributed with version 4.97, it's around line 405:

```
{Set this option to require the presence of the Delphi IDE to report memory
 leaks. This option has no effect if the option "EnableMemoryLeakReporting"
 is not also set.}
{.$define RequireIDEPresenceForLeakReporting}
```

Make sure the `.` is in the last line (before the `$define`) and rebuild your project.

@wades discovered that there's another setting, immediately below the one I mentioned, `RequireDebuggerPresenceForLeakReporting`, which defaults to being on. Disable it by adding a period right after the opening brace:

```
{Set this option to require the program to be run inside the IDE debugger to
 report memory leaks. This option has no effect if the option
 "EnableMemoryLeakReporting" is not also set.}
{$define RequireDebuggerPresenceForLeakReporting}
```

(Adding to this answer by @wades' request.)

Comment: No, this is not it. RequreIDEPresenceForLeakReporting is already off.

Comment: But this was a clue... the option of interest turns out to be RequireDebuggerPresenceForLeakReporting, which defaults to "on" in v4.99.

Comment: @wades, thanks. You should post an answer indicating that, or if you prefer I'll update my answer to include it, for others that may find this in the future. (Not sure how I missed it when I posted the answer above, as it's the very next entry in the `FastMM4Options.inc` file.)

Comment: please update the answer to add a mention of the RequireDebugger... flag, and I'll accept that. Thanks.